# Example of an Fmap to distinguish from map?

Tags: haskell, functor

My understanding is that the difference between map and fmap is that the latter can return a function?

I'm studying the functors section of this http://learnyouahaskell.com and some of the explanation is a bit unclear.

Map and fmap behave identically in the following:

```
let exMap = map (+1) [1..5]
let exFMap = fmap (+1) [1..5]
```

What is a good example of an fmap returning a function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, the difference is that `fmap` applies to any functor. For instance:

```
readLine :: IO String           -- read a line
fmap length readLine :: IO Int  -- read a line and count its length

Just 4 :: Maybe Int
fmap (+10) (Just 4) :: Maybe Int  -- apply (+10) underneath Just
                                  -- returns (Just 14)
```

`map` turns `a -> b` into a function `[] a -> [] b` (usually written as `[a] -> [b]`).

`fmap` turns `a -> b` into a function `f a -> f b`for any functor `f`, not only for `f = []`. The examples above chose `f = IO` and `f = Maybe`.

Comment: Could you take this a step further and differentiate, in simple terms, how functors differ from applicative functors?

Comment: If you have `a->b` and `f a`, when `f` is a functor, you can get `f b` using `fmap`. However, if you have `f (a->b)` and `f a`, you can not get `f b`: the function is wrapped underneath `f` and there's no way to make it interact with its argument. Applicative functors instead define an additional operation `<*>` allowing for that.

Comment: One available functor is "reader` which indeed relates to functions, but now may not be the best stage to learn about it.

Answer (score 7):

It would help to look at the type signatures for each function, let's start with the `map` function you are looking at:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

As you can see, this `map` function operates on lists.  Logically however, there are many data structures which can be mapped over.  Here are some other possible maps:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> Map k a -> Map k b
map :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
map :: (a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b
```

This is just the tip of the iceberg, many things can be mapped!

In languages that don't support type classes, this could be the world as you know it.  There are simply many `map` functions and you have to qualify them with an appropriate module type to distinguish which `map` you actually mean.  Not so in Haskell!

Now let's look at `fmap`:

```
fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

This function has exactly the same form as those shown above but works on anything which is a functor.

Functor is defined like this:

```
class  Functor f  where
    fmap        :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    (<$)        :: a -> f b -> f a
    (<$)        =  fmap . const
```

Hopefully this makes it obvious that a functor is simply *something that supports being mapped over.*

Therefore `fmap` is general, while `map` is specific.

Comment: You should clarify that you can't `fmap` over `Text` or `ByteString`, though, since they are not functors.

Comment: @chi I'll just replace them with better examples.

Comment: @TheInnerLight could you give an example of applying this to a binary tree of type data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)?

Answer (score 2):

`fmap` is more general than `map` - and indeed for lists there is no difference - here you have `map == fmap`.

Let us begin with the definition of `fmap`

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> (f a -> f b)
```

this essentially says you can turn a simple function into a function that transforms containers into containers of the same shape but different elements.

```
instance Functor [] where
   fmap = map

instance Functor Maybe where
   fmap _ Nothing = Nothing
   fmap f (Just something) = Just (f something)
```

there are many more, I think almost every container with a single type parameter can be a functor

As an exercise you can try to define an instance for

```
data Tree a = Tree a [a]
```

for the usage of `fmap` see @chi's answer.